# rows sql is null, how to fix it?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
<?php
    $sql = "(SELECT dari FROM mapping WHERE author = '$_SESSION[user]')
    UNION
    (SELECT ke FROM mapping WHERE author = '$_SESSION[user]')";

    $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    if(!empty($rows['dari'])) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['dari']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['dari']; ?></option> <?php
        } else {?>
            <option value="A1">A1</option><?php
        } 
    }
 ?>
```

menu option with value A1 can not appear in the form

Comment: Do you have ran your query in MySql with a client replacing the vars for real values?

Comment: yes sir @Mauricio , I have tried it and its value can change ... but if there is no data,, menu option can not appear in form with value a1

Comment: Your question is not clear, what is the expected behavior?

Comment: I expect if the data does not exist then the value of the option in the select menu is a1, @Mauricio

Comment: How many rows do you expect, one, two or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need enter to the block at least once

```
do 
{
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);
    if (null !== $rows && !empty($rows['dari']))
    { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['dari']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['dari']; ?></option> <?php
    }
    else
    { ?>
        <option value="A1">A1</option><?php
    }
} while ($rows);
```

Comment: @Lato237 if the answer is correct please mark up as correct, thanks.